# Divide two xts time series in for loop maintaining xts time

Tags: r, for-loop, xts

I have multiple `xts` time series where the `index()` is the same for all. I would like to divide two series and insert them in an empty matrix and then apply this to other pairs and maintain the time series.

I have tried various ways in the loop: such as simple dividing of the columns `close.price.ratio[,i] <- close.price[,cor.ticker[i,1]]/close.price[,cor.ticker[i,2]]` and `mapply('/',close.price['APC.Close'],close.price['CVX.Close'],SIMPLFY=F)`. However the `close.price.ratio` matrix always loses the indexing and is not a `xts` series.

Just dividing two columns results in keeping the `xts` indexing. 
Grateful for any help.

```
> head(close.price)
           KO.Close PEP.Close EOG.Close NBL.Close CVX.Close XOM.Close COG.Close APC.Close APA.Close
2014-01-02    40.66     82.10    165.02     66.59    124.14     99.75     38.17     78.56     85.48
2014-01-03    40.46     82.24    164.56     66.14    124.35     99.51     37.95     78.31     85.54
2014-01-06    40.27     82.28    164.02     65.75    124.02     99.66     38.20     78.34     86.31
2014-01-07    40.39     83.48    166.85     65.85    125.07    101.07     38.87     79.84     87.90
2014-01-08    39.94     83.24    166.78     65.71    123.29    100.74     38.75     79.04     86.65
2014-01-09    39.73     82.85    167.00     65.35    123.29     99.76     37.44     79.08     86.09

str(close.price)
An 'xts' object on 2014-01-02/2014-10-03 containing:
  Data: num [1:191, 1:9] 40.7 40.5 40.3 40.4 39.9 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:9] "KO.Close" "PEP.Close" "EOG.Close" "NBL.Close" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
 $ src    : chr "yahoo"
 $ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2014-10-06 18:16:04"
>
```

My code trying to divide the pairs according to the following vector

```
head(cor.ticker)
     [,1]        [,2]           
[1,] "PEP.Close" "KO.Close" 
[2,] "CVX.Close" "KO.Close"  
[3,] "APC.Close" "KO.Close"   
[4,] "APA.Close" "KO.Close"   
[5,] "EOG.Close" "PEP.Close" 
[6,] "CVX.Close" "PEP.Close"

close.price.ratio <- matrix(,nrow=nrow(close.price),ncol=nrow(cor.ticker))
for (i in 1:nrow(cor)){
  close.price.ratio[,i] <- close.price[,cor.ticker[i,1]]/close.price[,cor.ticker[i,2]] 
  colnames(close.price.ratio) <- c(cor.ticker[,3])
}
> head(close.price.ratio)
       PEP.KO   CVX.KO   APC.KO   APA.KO  EOG.PEP  CVX.PEP  
[1,] 2.019183 3.053123 1.932120 2.102312 2.009988 1.512058 
[2,] 2.032625 3.073406 1.935492 2.114187 2.000973 1.512038 
[3,] 2.043208 3.079712 1.945369 2.143283 1.993437 1.507292 
[4,] 2.066848 3.096559 1.976727 2.176281 1.998682 1.498203 
[5,] 2.084126 3.086880 1.978968 2.169504 2.003604 1.481139 
[6,] 2.085326 3.103197 1.990435 2.166876 2.015691 1.488111
```

resulting in a not `xts` matrix. Trying to define `rownames` did not work either. Many thanks!

Comment: You correctly pre-allocate `close.price.ratio`, but you do so as a matrix, not an xts object. `close.price.ratio[,i] <-` is not going to coerce `close.price.ratio` to an xts object just because the RHS of the expression happens to be one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
get.column <- function(i) close.price[,corr.ticker[i,1]]/close.price[,corr.ticker[i,2]]
result     <- do.call(cbind,lapply(1:nrow(corr.ticker),get.column))
names(result) <- corr.ticker[,1]
result
#            PEP.Close CVX.Close APC.Close APA.Close EOG.Close CVX.Close
# 2014-01-02  2.019183  3.053123  1.932120  2.102312  2.009988  1.512058
# 2014-01-03  2.032625  3.073406  1.935492  2.114187  2.000973  1.512038
# 2014-01-06  2.043208  3.079712  1.945369  2.143283  1.993437  1.507292
# 2014-01-07  2.066848  3.096559  1.976727  2.176281  1.998682  1.498203
# 2014-01-08  2.084126  3.086880  1.978968  2.169504  2.003604  1.481139
# 2014-01-09  2.085326  3.103197  1.990435  2.166876  2.015691  1.488111
```

This also works and might be a little faster.

```
do.call(cbind,mapply(function(x,y) close.price[,x]/close.price[,y],
                     corr.ticker[,1],corr.ticker[,2],SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
```

I think your problem is that, in the statement

```
close.price.ratio[,i] <- close.price[,cor.ticker[i,1]]/close.price[,cor.ticker[i,2]]
```

the RHS is evaluated as an xts object but coerced to a matrix because of the way you have written the LHS. Using `do.call(cbind,lapply(...))` avoids that by creating the columns separately and binding them together at the end. Note that `cbind.xts(...)` is the same as `merge.xts(...)` - it matches based on `index(...)`.